# Proper implementation of maintaining user authentication when browser is closed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, refresh-token, cookie-httponly

I'm using HTTP only with a Refresh token for user authentication. However, I'm really confused about how other platforms maintain user auth even after the browser is closed. For instance, how does Facebook/Meta automatic login work after the browser is closed? The only thing I know is storing tokens in local storage, but I know it's not a good idea to store confidential data in browser storage.

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way of doing this?